What is the new best known bound on the number of Riemann zeta function zeros with real part 3/4?
According to the popular news articles at https://www.science.org/content/article/sensational-breakthrough-marks-step-toward-revealing-hidden-structure-prime-numbers and https://www.quantamagazine.org/sensational-proof-delivers-new-insights-into-prime-numbers-20240715/, the new preprint at https://arxiv.org/abs/2405.20552 improves the best known bound on the number of Riemann zeta function zeros $s$ with real part $\mathrm{Re}(s) = 3/4$. But neither article actually states that new bound, and I can't find it in the preprint (in terms that I can understand, not being an expert in this field).
What exactly is the bound, stated in the simplest possible self-contained form? This statement does not need to reference any of the steps in the proof.

I think I've figured it out.
Before this paper was written, there were two known bounds on the grown of the Riemann zeta zeros:

Ingham proved the bound $$N(\sigma, T) = O\left( T^{\frac{3(1-\sigma)}{2-\sigma} + o(1)} \right) \text{ as }\ T\ \to \infty.$$

Huxley proved the bound $$N(\sigma, T) = O\left( T^{\frac{3(1-\sigma)}{3 \sigma - 1} + o(1)} \right) \text{ as }\ T\ \to \infty.$$


Ingham's bound was tighter for $\sigma \in \left[ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4} \right)$, while Huxley's bound was tighter for $\sigma \in \left( \frac{3}{4}, 1 \right]$. Along the line $\sigma = \frac{3}{4}$, both bounds coincided at $$N(\sigma = 3/4,\ T) = O\left( T^{\frac{3}{5} + o(1)} \right) \text{ as }\ T\ \to \infty.$$
This new paper proves the new bound (Theorem 1.2) $$N(\sigma, T) = O\left( T^{\frac{3(1-\sigma)}{2 - \sigma} + o(1)} \right) \text{ as }\ T\ \to \infty.$$
This new bound is looser than Ingham's bound for $\sigma \in [1/2, 7/10)$ and is looser than Huxley's bound for $\sigma \in (8/10, 1]$, so it provides no information within either of those strips. But for $\sigma \in (7/10, 8/10)$, it is (slightly) tighter than both. Only within this strip does the new bound improve upon previously known bounds.
The authors get the new bound $$N(\sigma, T) = O\left( T^{\frac{30(1-\sigma)}{13} + o(1)} \right) \text{ as }\ T\ \to \infty$$ that they state in the abstract and in equation (1.4) by combining Ingham's bound over the interval $\sigma \in [1/2, 7/10]$ with the new bound from their Theorem 1.2 over the interval $\sigma \in [7/10, 1]$ (not $\sigma < 7/10$ as Dietrich Burde stated in their answer). This bound is actually looser than other known bounds throughout the entire interval $\sigma \in [1/2, 1]$ (except at $\sigma = 7/10$ and $\sigma = 1$, where it matches the best known bounds by construction). I'm not entirely clear why the authors chose to highlight this looser bound in their abstract, instead of the tighter bound given in Theorem 1.2. I guess they wanted to be able to present a single bound of the form $$N(\sigma, T) = O\left( T^{c (1-\sigma) + o(1)} \right) \text{ as }\ T\ \to \infty$$ for some single constant $c$, rather than having to give a piecewise expression defined separately over multiple intervals within $\sigma \in [1/2, 1]$.

The paper by Guth and Maynard proves the following, see Theorem $1.2$.
Theorem. Denote by $N(\sigma, T)$ the number of zeros $\rho$ of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ with real part $\ge \sigma$ and absolute value of the imaginary part $\le T$. Then
$$
N(\sigma,T) \ll T^{\frac{15(1-\sigma)}{3+5\sigma}+o(1)}.
$$
When $\sigma\le 7/10$, then this yields
$$
N(\sigma,T) \ll T^{\frac{30(1-\sigma)}{13}+o(1)}.
$$
The exponent $30/13$ improves on the previous exponent of $12/5$ due to Huxley. This may not seem much, but it is very difficult to improve exponents in general for such problems. As an application, the bounds for the count of primes in short intervals are improved.
In the proof of the theorem one sees that one may restrict to the case that $7/10\le \sigma\le 8/10$, containing the interesting $3/4$, see page $44$.

in the arxiv  piece, I think you mean theorem 1.2  on page 2,   and $\sigma \leq \frac{7}{10}.$

@WillJagy Yes, thank you!

For those not familiar with the $\ll$ asymptotic notation, $f(T) \ll g(T)$ means that $f(T) = O(g(t))$. (I find it a bit confusing that the authors use both Bachmann–Landau notation and Vinogradov notation in the same equation!)

If $\sigma < 7/10$, then $\frac{15 (1 - \sigma))}{3 + 5 \sigma} > \frac{30 (1 - \sigma)}{13}$. So the second bound is tighter than the first one. How does the second bound follow from the first one? Doesn't the first bound imply the second bound if $\sigma \geq 7/10$, not $\sigma \leq 7/10$?

@tparker  suggest you read  the arxiv piece itself  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2405.20552
